# JAVA - Getting null values from SOAP UI while testing SOAP Web Services

Tags: java, soap, axis, soap-client

I am working on SOAP Client using `AXIS 1.4` generated classes. while testing from SoAP UI , getting the values(Title & LastName fileds as shown in below code) as null.

for all fields which are available in ApplicationPersonEntity class getting as null.

Please find the code as below:

```
public class ApplicationCustomerEntity implements java.io.Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "People")
    private List<ApplicationPersonEntity> people;

    //Setters & getters

     // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(ApplicationCustomerEntity.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationCustomerEntity"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("people");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "People"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationPersonEntity"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        elemField.setItemQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationPersonEntity"));
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        }

        //Serilizer & Deserilizer methods
}

ApplicationPersonEntity.java

public class ApplicationPersonEntity implements Serializable
{


    @XmlElement(name = "Title")
    protected String title;
    @XmlElement(name = "LastName")
    protected String lastName;

    //Consctor& Setters getters

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(ApplicationPersonEntity.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationPersonEntity"));

          org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("title");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "Title"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("lastName");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "LastName"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
    }

    //Serilizer & De Serilizer methods
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using below tags:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="People")
@XmlElement(name="ApplicationPersonEntity")
private List<ApplicationPersonEntity> people;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ApplicationCustomerEntity.java`
Instead of

```
typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationCustomerEntity"));
```

try this
Suppose your ApplicationCustomerEntity.java is used under CustomerList.java

```
typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://Services/CustomerList/ApplicationCustomerEntity", ">ApplicationCustomerEntity"));
```

In `ApplicationPersonEntity.java` instead of

```
typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("*..Services", "ApplicationPersonEntity"));
```

try this

```
typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://Services/CustomerList/ApplicationCustomerEntity/ApplicationPersonEntity", ">ApplicationPersonEntity"));
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_soap.asp

Comment: After made the changes as above even not working. Please help on this. @Parth Kansara

Comment: I have updated the answer try this way. @RajeswariReddy